# JavaRx on Android: Observe if multiple files have downloaded

Tags: android, file, download, rx-java

I have an ArrayList of articles, where each article contains an image url.

Also I have function downloadImage(url), which downloads and saves an image from an url to the device.

Now I want to download all images for every article (every download in it's own thread?) and proceed action when all images are downloaded.

How can I do that with RX?

Thanks!

Edit:
Thanks to Dave for the answer. It did the trick, but there is one thing I have to correct: if you have a non-iterable object (like Article is in my case) you need to use Observable.just() instead of Observable.from().

```
Observable
.from(articles)
.flatMap(article -> 
    Observable
        .just(article)
        .doOnNext(a -> downloadImage(a.imageUrl))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
)
.doOnError(t -> logError(t))
.subscribe();
```

Comment: Hi, Its been a while since you asked this question, but I am also facing same problem but I don't know how to use your answer.. can you help me on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to download each article image url in a separate thread:

```
Observable
    .from(articles)
    .flatMap(article -> 
        Observable
            .from(article)
            .doOnNext(a -> downloadImage(a.imageUrl))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    )
    .doOnError(t -> logError(t))
    .subscribe();
```